# how to parse value from previous tab to the next tab?

Tags: c#

i'm a beginner in C#, and right now i'm having a problem to get the value from the previous tab to display it on the next tab. can anyone tell me how to parse the value from the previous tab so that i can display it on the next tab?

Comment: what value? We need more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If** you are referring to the TabControl object in Windows Forms
and **If** you want to get the value of a specific control (e.g. label, text box etc) then you should refer to the desired inner control through the following property

```
TabControl.Controls["NameOfControl"]
```

Then, you can get whatever value you wish. If the value you seek is retrieved through a specific control property, you'll need to cast the appropriate type.

Answer (score 0):

Change the modifier type of the control or object, then it will be available.

Answer (score 0):

without knowing exactly what you are after try this and see if anything in there is useful:

http://yevol.com/en/vcsharp/applicationdesign/Lesson20.htm